# Is the Spartageskarte valid to Tirano?

Tags: trains, italy, switzerland

The Swiss [*Spartageskarte*](https://www.sbb.ch/de/abos-billette/billette-schweiz/tageskarten/spartageskarte.html) is a day pass valid throughout the regular Swiss railway network.  The *Rhätische Bahn* has trains that continue to Tirano in Italy.  Considering that a regular single ticket Tirano – Basel is CHF 116, a *Spartageskarte* could be an attractive alternative that is somewhat cheaper while retaining same-day travel flexibility.  The first 3 km or so of this journey are in Italy.  Is the *Spartageskarte* valid on trains to and from Tirano?

Comment: What does _Rhätische Bahn_  say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [SBB page on the Saver Day Pass](https://www.sbb.ch/en/travelcards-and-tickets/tickets-for-switzerland/day-pass/saver-day-pass.html) has a link on the bottom to a map of the Swiss rail network, showing what types of passes are valid on which lines. As the Saver Day Pass uses the GA network, you can take any train or bus shown in a solid color on the map. As you can see, the line between Tirano and St. Moritz or Chur is solid red on the map and the Saver Day Pass is thus valid for a ticket on it.

However, some trains on this route are the panoramic Berina Express trains. If you wish to take one of these, then, in addition to a ticket, you must [additionally purchase a seat reservation](https://www.rhb.ch/en/panoramic-trains/bernina-express#info), and the cost of this reservation (currently CHF 20–26 depending on the time of year) must be paid in addition to the cost of the day pass.

Comment: I think the seat reservation only applies to the Bernina Express, not to local trains also running from Tirano to Pontresina with onward connections?  But still a good point, that I cannot simply board _any_ train from Tirano with this pass.

Comment: @gerrit Ah, thanks. I've edited my response to clarify.

Comment: The extra reservation cost only applies to the panoramic cars. The Bernina Express trains are attached to the rear of regular regional trains where no surcharge is required.